# Move code from one repo to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a github repository called A. It's connected to heroku-A and the website is up and running. I did changes locally to the code, but I don't want those changes to show on repository A or heroku-A. I want to push the code to a totally new repo. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here would be the procedure:

1. Create a new git branch (so that code is separate from your other repo)

   `git checkout -b <new_branch>`
2. Add a remote pointing to your new repository

   `git remote add <new_repository_url> <new_repository_name>`
3. Push the new branch to the new repository:

   `git push <new_repository_name> <new_branch>`

Comment: Thanks Derek, small question. Why are you creating a new git branch in the same repo?

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner Given you have a running site on `master`, it is a good practice to keep any changes you make on a different branch.  This if beneficial for a few reasons 1) If you use automated deployment in the future, it keeps your production and test code separate 2) it tracks the status of your production code and 3) prevents you from an accidental push ruining your site.

Comment: Got it. But I don't want any of the local changes I made to show up on the current repository. I want all that to be on a totally new repo

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner by current repository, do you mean the local one, or the remote one?

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner this approach lets you quickly switch between versions of the repository on your local machine.  `git checkout master` takes you to the current production version of your site and `git checkout <new_branch>` takes you to the new version of your site.

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner if you want a totally new copy of the repository- you can just copy the entire folder (including the hidden `.git` file), but this is bad practice.

Comment: current repo meaning the local one. So on github.com, there is a repo called A, this is connected to Heroku A. I changed a lot of the code locally. Now, the code in my remote github repo A and my local code is extremely different. I don't want the code in remote github A to change at all. I want to push all the local code I have now into a totally different remote repo. I don't want any new branches in my remote github A. Is that what happens with your answer? Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner why is it that you want this behavior?

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner the code I posted will not create branches in the A remote repository.  A branch is created when you run `git push <repository_name> <branch_name>` so as long as you run `git push origin master` and `git push repo_B branch_B` you should be good!